# Laravel strange date formatting

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I inherited a Laravel project and am running into a strange issue with date formatting.

I get the following error:

> InvalidArgumentException in Carbon.php line 582
>
> Unexpected data found.
>
> Unexpected data found.
>
> The separation symbol could not be found
>
> Unexpected data found
>
> Trailing data

The stack track shows the problem has to do with a date time conversion:

> at Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s.u', 'Oct 10 2017 02:31:04:493PM') in Model.php line 3003

I can see that there is a weird date format with `02:31:04:493PM` as the time. I don't know where that format is coming from and I've spent literally all day trying.

All of the date formats in the application code are of the 'Y-m-d H:i:s.u' or 'Y-m-d H:i:s' format. I don't know where this invalid one with the `:` before microseconds is coming from and I can't seem to find it anywhere in the code.

I've checked in Model.php, Carbon.php, all of the app Models that inherit from Model, etc. When I run the project on localhost environment, everything loads fine, but when I try on the dev environment, this error happens.

The leads me to believe it is something environment specific, but I don't know enough about Apache/PHP/SQL Server to know where the formatting is coming from. The data in the database appears just fine as normal datetime values.

Any ideas or suggestions on where to look?

Comment: Check your controllers? One thing you can try is utilize Eloquent's [observers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#observers), and log a trace in there to find out where the bad format is coming from.

Comment: Thanks, I had been working backwards from the controllers, but they basically just inherit the Model.php. I'll have to review this observers stuff and see if I can figure out how to implement it so I can at least get a better idea of what is going on. There's got to be something different between the environments, but even with a full DIFF of the project, I wasn't able to find it. Very odd. These SqlServerGrammar scripts don't get cached, do they?

Comment: Not usually, I don't think.

Comment: Thanks @aynber. I ended up trying to cast the dates in the DB response with the correct format and it resolved the issue. I think there must be some environment-specific difference in PHP or the PDO library that is causing the DB dates to come back differently by default.

Comment: @all I'd like to close this Question out as the issue appears to be related to server configuration. Not sure if I should just delete the question or Vote to Close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by migrating our PHP server from FreeBSD to IIS.

Our environment did not have the appropriate PDO SQLSRV drivers to communicate to our SQL Server database properly and Microsoft doesn't provide pre-compiled versions for FreeBSD.

Our organization did not need to use FreeBSD and so we moved to IIS because it was easier for our new members to manage.  With IIS, we were able to download the Microsoft PDO SQLSRV drivers that are compiled for IIS/Windows and this made the DB queries yield the correct date formats.